# Cant see TextView in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-fragments

Everything I have displays my listview properly but it will not show my second TextView which should be part of the listview.  This will probably be a really simple mistake and take an experienced android user 30 seconds to spot.

Here is my code: This is one item of a listView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<TableRow>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Title"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Choice"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

</TableRow>
```

This is my fragment xml containing the listview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none" >
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
        android:text="Handbells" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
        android:text="Towerbells" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my adapter code:

```
public class Top3CustomAdapter<String> extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private ArrayList<String> entries;

public Top3CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId){
    super(context, textViewResourceId);
}

public Top3CustomAdapter(Activity a, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<String> entries) {
    super(a, textViewResourceId, entries);
    this.entries = entries;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {

        LayoutInflater vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.listview_top_3, null);

    }

    TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Title);
    TextView choice = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Choice);

    title.setText(entries.get(0) + "");
    choice.setText(entries.get(1) + "");

    return v;
}
```

}

This is my fragment code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    //This layout contains your list view 
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_activity_start, parent, false);

       //now you must initialize your list view
       ListView listview =(ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);

       ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
       items.add(0,"Method");
       items.add(1,"Aberafan");

       ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items); 
       listview.setAdapter(adapter);  

        //To have custom list view use this : you must define CustomeAdapter class
        // listview.setadapter(new CustomeAdapter(getActivity()));
       //getActivty is used instead of Context
     return view;
}
```

Comment: Returns `entries.get(1)` any data?

Comment: Tried replacing entries with a string and it doesnt work either

Comment: I'm suspicious of your use of `entries.get(1)` and `entries.get(0)` in your `getView` function. Why are you not using `position` to get the values? You should be getting two strings per row for use in your row's layout.

Comment: I've tested it by replacing entries.get(x) with strings and same result.

Comment: I think the ListView doesn't like your TableLayout. You might try using a LinearLayout with a horizontal orientation.

Comment: Its not the TableLayout, Got a linearLayout and its the same.  If i take the title.setText(entries.get(0) + ""); away it makes no difference.  It will only change the text if you change items.add(0,"ANY TEXT");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `onCreateView` function for your fragment, you have these two lines:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items); 
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

this means that the list view is using a standard `ArrayAdapter` with a `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` layout for each row. Instead of the custom adapter and row layout that you thought you were using.

Comment: how can  i show my contents in listview using ListFragment   public class LocationListFragment extends ListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Location>>{